# C# file not saving on correct folder

Tags: c#, file

I Need save the txt file on a correct create folder. But its saving on C:\Nova Pasta i need save on "C:\Nova pasta\"+valor.retorna_nome+comboBox1.Text whats is wrong ?

```
private void btn_SaveFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    objSQL.Search_RGP_CadastroPrint(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text), str_list);
    objSQL.SearchPrint(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text));

    string path = @"C:\Nova pasta\"+valor.retorna_nome+comboBox1.Text;

    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

    }
    StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path + ".txt");

    file.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    file.WriteLine("Nome: " + valor.retorna_nome);
    file.WriteLine("RGP: " + comboBox1.Text);
    file.WriteLine("Endereço: " + valor.retorna_endereco);
    file.WriteLine("Telefone: " + valor.retorna_telefone + " Celular: " + valor.retorna_celular + "\r\n");
    str_list.ForEach(file.WriteLine);

    file.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is `valor.retorna_nome` and `comboBox1.Text` supposed to represent?

Comment: its 2 string. valor.retorna_nome return a name and combobox1.text return a string number

Comment: When you add a breakpoint on `string path = @"C:\Nova pasta\"+valor.retorna_nome+comboBox1.Text;` what is it's value? Also consider using `Path.Combine`

Comment: is `path` meant to be a file name, or a directory name? You appear to be treating it as both.

Comment: humm first verify if folder exist if dont exist create a new folder, and in this new folder create a new txt file.

Comment: From what you've explained, what your question asks, and what I'm seeing in the code, I can only surmise that your code is working as intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say `valor.retorna_nome` is "hello", and `comboBox1.Text` is "world". Your code does the following:

```
string path = @"C:\Nova pasta\"+valor.retorna_nome+comboBox1.Text;
// -> path = "C:\Nova pasta\helloworld"

if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    // -> created directory "C:\Nova pasta\helloworld"
}

StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path + ".txt");
// -> writes to file "C:\Nova pasta\helloworld.txt"
```

So it's doing exactly what you told it to. What would you like the directory to be called? And the filename?

Comment: The problem is that he is not doing it. If it exists the way just create the file within it, if it does not exist create the folder and then create the file in.

Answer (score 1):

Your String path is equals to something like that : "C:\Nova pasta\aNameXXX"

where :

aName = valor.retorna_nome

XXX = Combobox1.Text

You create a directory, this must success, but after that your file path is : 
 path+.txt : "C:\Nova pasta\aNameXXX.txt"

it's creating a file named (aNameXXX.txt)  next to your folder.

you need to add an "\" and a name to your file to make a path like : "C:\Nova pasta\aNameXXX\FILENAME.txt"

```
StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path + "\" + FILENAME + ".txt");
```